# Как сделать так что бы парсинг участников начинался с N участника?

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, telegram

Например я хочу что бы пирсинг начинался с человека под номером 51
как мне это сделать?
Вот код:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import os, sys
import configparser
import csv
import time

re="\033[1;31m"
gr="\033[1;32m"
cy="\033[1;36m"

def banner():
    print(f"""
{re}╔╦╗{cy}┌─┐┌─┐┌─┐┌─┐┬─┐{re}╔═╗
{re} ║ {cy}├─┐├┤ ├─┘├─┤├┬┘{re}╚═╗
{re} ╩ {cy}└─┘└─┘┴  ┴ ┴┴└─{re}╚═╝
by https://github.com/elizhabs

        """)

cpass = configparser.RawConfigParser()
cpass.read('config.data')

try:
    api_id = cpass['cred']['id']
    api_hash = cpass['cred']['hash']
    phone = cpass['cred']['phone']
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
except KeyError:
    os.system('clear')
    banner()
    print(re+"[!] run python3 setup.py first !!\n")
    sys.exit(1)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    os.system('clear')
    banner()
    client.sign_in(phone, input(gr+'[+] Enter the code: '+re))
 
os.system('clear')
banner()
chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]
 
result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
chats.extend(result.chats)
 
for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue
 
print(gr+'[+] Choose a group to scrape members :'+re)
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(gr+'['+cy+str(i)+gr+']'+cy+' - '+ g.title)
    i+=1
 
print('')
g_index = input(gr+"[+] Enter a Number : "+re)
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]
 
print(gr+'[+] Fetching Members...')
time.sleep(1)
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)
 
print(gr+'[+] Saving In file...')
time.sleep(1)
with open("members.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id'])
    for user in all_participants:
        if user.username:
            username= user.username
        else:
            username= ""
        if
```

user.first_name:
first_name= user.first_name
else:
first_name= ""
if user.last_name:
last_name= user.last_name
else:

Comment: Пирсинг чего? Сосков? :D

Comment: Если перебор участников делается в `for user in all_participants:`, то чтобы пропустить первые 50 можно так: `for user in all_participants[50:]:`. Кст, `all_participants = []` не нужен, вы ведь список и так получаете сразу на следующей строке